# Can women watch the football of men? (Shi'a view)

Tags: halal-haram, women, shiism, non-mahram, sports

According to the 30th verse of Surah Al-Nur:

> قُل لِّلْمُؤْمِنِينَ يَغُضُّوا مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِمْ وَيَحْفَظُوا
>   فُرُوجَهُمْ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ أَزْكَىٰ لَهُمْ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ خَبِيرٌ بِمَا
>   يَصْنَعُونَ ٣٠
>
> Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard
>   their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is
>   Acquainted with what they do. (30)
>   [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/24:30)

So it shows the significance of controlling of our eyes in looking at non-Mahrams.

I was wondering what the view of contemporary Shi'a scholars such as Ayatollah Khamenei is  regarding watching football matches? (For women, to watch football matches of men)

Answer (score 1):

> Can women watch the football of men? (Shi'a view)

According to Ayatollah Khamenei as a famous Shia Islam Marja'-al-Taqlid, it is permissible if this is without Reibeh (enjoyment) and vice (sin). Meanwhile, based on my examination, almost all of Shia contemporary Marajas/scholar have such view.

**Note:** Reibeh (in the above-mentioned explanation, in the issue of looking at non-mahram) as a Fiqh's expression is interpreted to "the fear -having the probability- of falling in haram(sin)/Fitna and to what which is occurring (in the mind) ...

---

**Source:**

[article.tebyan.net](https://article.tebyan.net/181896/%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%85-%D9%87%D8%A7-%D9%81%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A8%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%86%D8%AF-%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D9%86%D9%87-)

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa29050)

[www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A8%D9%87)